# Как удалить пакет, установленный из deb файла?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, apt, deb

Скачал с официального сайта deb пакет для VirtualBox 6 версии.
Поставил.
В консоли появилась команда virtualbox.
Оказалось, что для работы мне нужна 5 версия.
Пытаюсь удалить установленную утилиту:

```
sudo apt remove --purge virtualbox
```

А мне говорят:

```
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
```

Как мне удалить данную утилиту?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрим откуда запускается команда:

`whereis virtualbox`

Узнаем имя пакета

`dpkg -S fullpath` где `fullpath` полный путь к исполняемому файлу (взять из результата предыдущей команды)

Удаляем используя имя пакета

`dpkg --remove packagename` где `packagename` имя пакета  (взять из результата предыдущей команды)

Answer (score 5):

дополнительные пути определения имени (помимо предложенного в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1155333/178576)):

1. уже по имени файла (если оно формировалось [по принятым правилам](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_debian_package_file_names) и не изменялось впоследствии) можно определить имя пакета: это все символы до первого символа `_`. например, если имя файла — `virtualbox-6.1_6.1.12-139181~Debian~buster_amd64.deb`, то имя пакета, содержащегося внутри — `virtualbox-6.1`.
2. если файл подвергался переименованию, но пока не удалён, можно узнать имя содержащегося в нём пакета, например, с помощью программы `dpkg-deb`:

   ```
   $ dpkg-deb -f virtualbox-6.1_6.1.12-139181~Debian~buster_amd64.deb Package
   virtualbox-6.1
   ```
3. если файл не сохранился, но известно, что имя установленного пакета содержит определённую строку (например, "box"), то можно поискать в базе *dpkg* частичное совпадение:

   ```
   $ dpkg -l '*box*'
   Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
   | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
   |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
   ||/ Name                        Version                 Architecture Description
   +++-===========================-=======================-============-===========
   ii  busybox                     1:1.30.1-4              amd64        Tiny utilit
   ii  virtualbox-6.1              6.1.12-139181~Debian~bu amd64        blablablabl
   ...
   ```

---

впрочем, и программам *apt/apt-get* можно передавать не только точное имя пакета, но и маску, под которую подпадает имя:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove 'virtualbox*'
```